# Center align content over image using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to `center align` the title, description, and button over the image on my site. Is there an efficient way of doing this? Maybe some custom CSS that would group them together and center them within the container?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
.text-container {
  position: relative;
}

.text-container .btn {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #181818;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.text-container:hover .btn {
  background-color: #545454;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay-header-first {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 25%; 
  left: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

.overlay-description-first {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 17%; 
  left: 20%;
  text-align: center;

}

.overlay-button-first {
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 11%; 
  left: 20%;  
}
```

```
<section id="tiles" data-sequence="100">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center pt-4 animatedParent animateOnce">
            <div class="col-md-6 pb-4 pb-lg-0 overlay text-container animated fadeIn slowest" data-id="1">
                  <a href="#"><img src="tree.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                  <a href="#"><h2 class="overlay-header-first mb-4">TITLE ONE</h2></a>
                  <p class="overlay-description-first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.<br>Elit ut ultrices pulvinar tristique.</p>
                  <a href="#"><btn class="btn btn-dark overlay-button-first">SHOP NOW</btn></a>                                                             
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 pb-4 pb-lg-0 overlay text-container animated fadeIn slowest" data-id="2">
                  <a href="#"><img src="tree.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
                  <a href="#"><h2 class="overlay-header-first mb-4">TITLE TWO</h2></a>
                  <p class="overlay-description-first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.<br>Elit ut ultrices pulvinar tristique.</p>  
                  <a href="#"><btn class="btn btn-dark overlay-button-first">SHOP NOW</btn></a>                                                             
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: css can't group stuff - you would need to wrap them in a div and centre that

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 5?

Comment: @Soheb I'm using Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

i add "text-wrapper" class & add some css to this  class.
Comment your unnecessary CSS

```css
.text-container {
  position: relative;
}

.text-container .btn {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #181818;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.text-container:hover .btn {
  background-color: #545454;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay-header-first {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1.8rem;


}

 .overlay-description-first {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1rem;
/*   position: absolute; 
  bottom: 17%; 
  left: 20%; */

} 

.overlay-button-first {
/*   position: absolute; 
  bottom: 11%; 
  left: 20%;   */
} 


.text-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
.text-container img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="tiles" data-sequence="100">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center pt-4 animatedParent animateOnce">
            <div class="col-md-6 pb-4 pb-lg-0 overlay text-container animated fadeIn slowest" data-id="1">
                  <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/22/21/57/apparel-1850804_960_720.jpg" class="img-fluid"></a>
              
              <div class="text-wrapper"
                  <a href="#"><h2 class="overlay-header-first mb-4">TITLE ONE</h2></a>
                  <p class="overlay-description-first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.<br>Elit ut ultrices pulvinar tristique.</p>
                  <a href="#"><btn class="btn btn-dark overlay-button-first">SHOP NOW</btn></a>      
      </div>
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add same class to that you want to center

```
<a href="#"><img src="tree.png" class="img-txt"></a>
<a href="#"><h2 class="overlay-header-first mb-4 img-txt">TITLE ONE</h2></a>
<p class="overlay-description-first img-txt ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing Elit ut ultrices pulvinar tristique.</p>
<a href="#"><btn class="btn btn-dark overlay-button-first img-txt">SHOP NOW</btn></a>
```

add css to `img-txt` like below

```
  .img-txt{
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   }
```

it will center the text on image

Comment: Thank you @Dinesh Karthik - This has centered the elements but they have now dropped off the image instead of overlaying - what is this fix for this?

Comment: try with changing position

Comment: This bit of css is the solution. I see no need sending my answer. The answer of @satish should solve the dropped problem you are facing. i.e remove the .img-txt class from the img tag, rap all the text tags( the 2as and 1p) inside a div and give it the .img-txt class. Then remove all the absolute positions you gave to the text tags. That's it

Answer (score 0):

Add align-content: center; for the wrapper class
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-content.asp - Link

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want, just put this inside and change the `<img class="post-img" src="tree.png">`

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.post {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.post-img {
  width: 100%;
}

.post-text {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.post-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.post-button {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="post">
            <img class="post-img"
                src="https://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/news/2016/09/08/107667228_beech-tree-NEWS_trans_NvBQzQNjv4BqplGOf-dgG3z4gg9owgQTXEmhb5tXCQRHAvHRWfzHzHk.jpg?imwidth=1400">
            <div class="post-text">
                <p class="post-title">TITLE TWO</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.<br>Elit ut ultrices pulvinar tristique.</p>
                <p class="post-button">SHOP NOW</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="post">
            <img class="post-img"
                src="https://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/news/2016/09/08/107667228_beech-tree-NEWS_trans_NvBQzQNjv4BqplGOf-dgG3z4gg9owgQTXEmhb5tXCQRHAvHRWfzHzHk.jpg?imwidth=1400">
            <div class="post-text">
                <p class="post-title">TITLE TWO</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.<br>Elit ut ultrices pulvinar tristique.</p>
                <p class="post-button">SHOP NOW</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap 4 or above, you can use this:

```css
.text-container {
  position: relative;
}

.text-container .btn {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #181818;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.text-container:hover .btn {
  background-color: #545454;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay-header-first {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.overlay-description-first {
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

/*using this style block, you can center the absolute positioned div*/
.divInfo{
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*This style add background opacity in the color definition last two digits */
.bg-lighter{
  background-color: #F8F9FADD !important;
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center pt-4 animatedParent animateOnce">
    <div class="col-md-12 pb-4 pb-lg-0 overlay text-container animated fadeIn slowest" data-id="1">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://www.sciencenewsforstudents.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/1030_LL_trees-1028x579.png" class="img-fluid">         </a>
      <!-- Added this part to content -->
      <div class="position-absolute divInfo d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="text-center bg-lighter text-dark p-3 shadow">
        <!-- ------------------------- -->
          <a href="#"><h2 class="overlay-header-first mb-4">TITLE ONE</h2></a>
          <p class="overlay-description-first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.<br>Elit ut ultrices pulvinar tristique.</p>
          <a href="#"><btn class="btn btn-dark overlay-button-first">SHOP NOW</btn></a>
        <!-- ------------------------- -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ------------------------- -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I changed some part of your code because Bootstrap has its own style, but not for everything.